# cakephp sessions

Tags: php, session, cakephp

I am a beginner with Cakephp and I have a big problem with sessions...

What's happening exactly

I start initialize the session with ajax calling a php file (a controller)
this is the url from ajax->url: http ://domain.com/things/view/0

I tried also without ajax by calling this url:
http ://domain.com/things/view/1

In both of cases session is iniatialized.
Below is the controller I use to iniatialize session

```
class ThingsController extends AppController {
    var $name = 'Things';
    var $components = array('Session');
    var $helpers = array('Html', 'Javascript', 'Ajax');
    var $uses = null;

    function index() {

        // preload dynamic data
        $this->set('data1', 'content will update here');
        $this->set('data2', 'here too');

        $this->render('neat');

    }

    function view($id, $idd) {

        if ($idd == 0) {
            $this->Session->write('language', 'ro');
        } else {
            $this->Session->write('language', 'en');
        }

        if (is_numeric($id)) {
            if ($id == 0) {
                $this->Session->write('language', 'ro');
            } else {
                $this->Session->write('language', 'en');
            }
        }


        $this->render('neat');
    } //view()
} //ThingsController
```

As you can see `if SESSION['language'] == 0 is ro else is en`

The rooter rule used is:

```
Router::connect('/things/:id/*', array('controller' => 'things', 'action' => 'view', 
'things'), array('pass' => 'id'));
```

But works also without this rule :)

Now in the page about the session works: http: //domain.com/despre-noi

I used this rooter:

```
Router::connect('/despre-noi/*', array('controller' => 'about', 'action' => 'display', 'about'));
```

And this controller

```
function display() {
    if (isset($_SESSION["language"])) {
        $language = $_SESSION["language"];
        $this->Session->write('language', $_SESSION["language"]);
    } else {
        $this->Session->write('language', 'ro');
        $language = "ro";
    }
    include('views/pages/'.$language.'.ctp');

    $this->layout = 'default';

    $this->About->id = 1;
    $this->set('post1', $this - > About - > read());

}
```

But in page partners :  http: //domain.com/parteneri

Where I used this rooter:

```
Router::connect('/parteneri/*', array('controller' => 'partner', 'action' => 'display', 'partner'));
```

and the folowing controller:

```
function display() {

    if (isset($_SESSION["language"])) {
        $language = $_SESSION["language"];
        $this->Session->write('language', $_SESSION["language"]);
    } else {
        $this->Session->write('language', 'ro');
        $language = "ro";
    }
    include('views/pages/'.$language.'.ctp');

    $this->layout = 'default';

    $this->set('posts', $this - > Partner - > find('all'));

}
```

it doesn't work..

This 2 pages are veri similiar with the difference that in the partner page I used `$this->set('posts', $this->Partner->find('all'));` and then in view with a `foreach()` I list the items and in the page about I read a row

```
$this->About->id = 1;
$this->set('post1', $this->About->read());
```

Might be this the problem...the 2 functions read() vs find()..or is just a coincidence?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

**First** make sure you have:

```
Configure::write('Session.save', 'php');
```

in your `app/config/core.php` file. The [Sessions Chapter](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1310/Sessions) of the [CakePHP book](http://book.cakephp.org) give some good examples on how to configure and use the Session Component.

Also, if you're going to use sessions (i.e. the `Session` component), you better put:

```
var $components = array('Session');
```

In your `AppController`. In this way *every controller* will have that component available.

**Second**, if you are using CakePHP's Session class to write session data, then you should not access that data directly (i.e. by calling `$_SESSION['language']`). This is bad practice since, if you ever decide to use `'database'` as a session storage or if CakePHP decides that Session data should be encrypted, then your code would break and you'd have no idea why.

In short, please use `$this->Session->read('language')` in your code (and also, take a look at the aforementioned [Sessions Chapter](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1310/Sessions), it also gives some good background.

Also, since what you want to achieve is Internationalization, after fixing your Controllers as per the pastes in my comments you have to absolutely take a look at the easy way for Localization by reading through the [CakePHP Internationalization Section](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1229/Internationalizing-Your-Application). There is a way to do things more easily and separate *presentation logic* from *presentation contents* in your views -- but that's material for another question ;)

Comment: Thanks for anwer.  In core.php I have Configure::write('Session.save', 'my_session'); and the i create the file my_sessions and put in it everything like in the books example. At the beging I save it in php like you said it doesn't.  Anyway Itried also calling like you advised me and still nothing...  The sessions acts like I am in other domain and of course it doesn't know nothing about it.. I also have this linex in core.php: Configure::write('Security.level', 'low');
Configure::write('Session.checkAgent', false);

Comment: I thought the problem is the router and I change the folowing router Router::connect('/parteneri/*', array('controller' => 'partner', 'action' => 'display', 'partner')); to load the about  page, for that I change the router to Router::connect('/parteneri/*', array('controller' => 'about', 'action' => 'display', 'about')); and it works ok, loads about page with the session initialized correctly. So the only problem should be in partner controller (both controllers - partner and about- are in the question's body)...but which is the error

Comment: I also want to mention that is output session in about controler: print_r($_SESSION); it outputs Array ( [Config] => Array ( [userAgent] => bacc67458f6a4db196762e81c0d9c341 [time] => 1303984020 [timeout] => 10 ) [language] => en ), but if I output it in partner controller it outputs Array ( ). So it forget everything about that session...: (   That's all I can say about my problem.  Thanks

Comment: quick question just to make sure: do you have var `$components = array('Session');` in your `PartnerController` class?

Comment: I updated the answer with how to always use the `Session` component (declaring the use in `AppController`)

Comment: Can you first try session usage by using `Configure::write('Session.save', 'php');` which is the most generic and should work out of the box?

Otherwise, I'd try to use them through: `Configure::write('Session.save', 'cake');`

Comment: Could you please paste your controller code (strip away sensitive info) in [pastebin](http://pastebin.com)

Comment: This is Partner Controller: http://pastebin.com/GSc46Yhe which doesn't work...The about controller which work:http://pastebin.com/hqHZifwV  and the controller used to change language is:http://pastebin.com/Tn1FC1F3.  Thanks a lot for your interest in my problem

Comment: I modified your controllers a little bit: [ThingsController](http://pastebin.com/U3sRkTXK) [AboutController](http://pastebin.com/efHxSmPL) [PartnerController](http://pastebin.com/sUG7UEAn) This is what CakePHP code should look like ;)

Comment: @Mihai take a look at the pastes in previous comment and the answer update, I think the Session storage is not your problem ;)

Comment: I am sorry but the problem is the session...  That include wasn't the view of the controller it was a file where I define some constants..  I used the code as in the example found here: http://www.prologictechnologies.in/kb/php/create-multi-language-site-using-cakephp/ .  This was with cookie and works fine...but I have to make it with sessions. It should be simple but...just modify $_COOKIE with $_SESSION in controller and use ajax to initialize the session...and the the big bug..in some pages the site knew about sessions in others din not ...

Comment: Thanks for your responses and advices you gave me, even if the problem still not solved I've learn something new  #
// use the following if you need to change the view path (which you do)
#
  $this->viewPath = 'pages'; I didn't know:)  I also hope you have somewhere the solution for the session.   Anyway i'm grateful for al you did for me. Thanks again

Comment: I've just solved the problem...in the controler pages I had 2 enters at the end of the file ...after deleting everything was ok with session....what a stupid thing...i lose 2 days to see them...if it shows at list the basic errors when make output before sessions starts...:(.   Anyway I'm happy i solved. Thanks again for your advices

Comment: Ah, that means the output was initiating the response. I always leave out the closing ?> tag. Still, I think that from how your question is formulated, the answer should get you running. Have fun!